# Why is this code giving me a null pointer exception?

Tags: c#

i am new to object oriented programming. why am i getting this nullpointerexception? a quick answer would help me a lot.

```
public static void Main(string[] args){
    Avatar person;

person.Speak();
}
public class Avatar{
    public Avatar(){}
    public void Speak(){ 
    Console.WriteLine("Avatar says Hello!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving the null pointer exception because
you did not create a new instance of the Avatar class.

To create a new instance do `Avatar person = new Avatar();`

Comment: Thanks for the help! Really appreciate it, hope i can keep this pace up while learning c#